# Add date time to the files in batch

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

This code reads files from folder and assign same date time to all.

Code:

```
@echo off
set datetime=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /s D:\v\*.*') do (
  echo %%~dpnx_%datetime%%%~xx>>C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\a.txt
)
move /y C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\a.txt C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\b.txt
```

Output:

```
a_08042016_095244.txt 
a_08042016_095244.txt
```

My requirement is to have different date time for two files so that we can differentiate with change in milliseconds.

Required output:

```
a_08042016_095244.txt 
a_08042016_095252.txt
```

Comment: For sorting purposes you should use YYYYMMDD date format.

Comment: @Pbies: Not trying to sort it.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Where is the output  `a_08042016_095244.txt` coming from? If I run your batch file I gete the expected output in `a.txt.` which is lines containing the full path of the file, for example `f:\v\A\C\D\a_8/01_111414.txt`. There cannot be two files with the same name.

Comment: You should probably do the set datetime inside your loop. Otherwise it will use the same date all the time.

Comment: @David:I ran the code just now and got the output as 
D:\v\a_08082016_160750.pdf
D:\v\b_08082016_160750.txt
D:\v\c_08082016_160750.xml. 
Here I don't need same datetime for all the files,it should be change in minutes or millseconds.
Expected Output:
D:\v\a_08082016_160750.pdf
D:\v\b_08082016_160753.txt
D:\v\c_08082016_160758.xml.

Comment: @user3051956 See my answer. You now have time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My requirement is to have different date time for two files

> so that we can differentiate with change in milliseconds.

You can use the file creation time to get a unique date/time value as it is unlikely that two files with the same name will have exactly the same creation time.

**test.bat:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /a-d /b /s f:\v\*.*') do (
  rem use file creation time to get unique timestamp.
  rem need to double up the \ for the wmic query.
  set _name=%%x
  set _name=!_name:\=\\!
  for /f %%t in ('wmic datafile where name^="!_name!" get creationdate ^| findstr /brc:[0-9]') do (
    set _datetime=%%t
    )
  rem strip last 4 characters as always the same
  echo %%~dpnx_!_datetime:~0,-4!%%~xx>>out.log
)
endlocal
```

**Example usage:**

```
F:\test>dir /a-d /b /s f:\v
f:\v\A\a.txt
f:\v\A\B\a.txt
f:\v\A\C\a.txt
f:\v\A\C\D\a.txt

F:\test>test

F:\test>type out.log
f:\v\A\a_20160804231753.551948.txt
f:\v\A\B\a_20160804231800.344348.txt
f:\v\A\C\a_20160804231803.581548.txt
f:\v\A\C\D\a_20160804231807.072814.txt
```

**Your batch file modified appropriately:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /a-d /b /s d:\v\*.*') do (
  rem use file creation time to get unique timestamp.
  rem need to double up the \ for the wmic query.
  set _name=%%x
  set _name=!_name:\=\\!
  for /f %%t in ('wmic datafile where name^="!_name!" get creationdate ^| findstr /brc:[0-9]') do (
    set _datetime=%%t
    )
  rem strip last 4 characters as always the same
  echo %%~dpnx_!_datetime:~0,-4!%%~xx>>C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\a.txt
)
move /y C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\a.txt C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\b.tx
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) - Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.
- [variable edit/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) - Edit and replace the characters assigned to a string variable.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Thanks a lot.it almost met my requirement.Just need one answer.Below is the output from above code: d:\v\a_20160805123421.176515+330.pdf
d:\v\b_20160805144032.522315+330.txt
d:\v\c_20160805144047.338797+330.xml.Can you explain this datetime--(20160805123421.176515+330).

Comment: @user3051956 Apologies I forgot to add a little bit of code to the answer. It has been updated. You wont see the `+330` any more (I intended to remove it as it is not necessary).

Comment: @user3051956 `.176515` is the milliseconds.

Comment: @user3051956 The `+330` is the number of minutes difference between your local time and Greenwich mean time. See [Converting WMI Dates to a Standard Date-Time Format](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156576.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the full meaning of all the parts of the date-time format.

Comment: @user3051956 `20160805123421` is `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`